# Multiple Google charts on page

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm currently trying to display 3 google chart on my asp.net MVC website.

I want those charts to be next to an other (on the same line) but for the moment I'm not able to make them appear one below an other (on the same column) and I don't know why...

The following code is only showing one chart ( the first one ) :

```
<div id="chart_divb">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Interventions');
            var data1=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chartToday));
            $.each(data1,function(index,value){
                data.addRows([[value.Item1, value.Item2]]);
            });
            var options = {'title':'Total Interventions on @(DateTime.Now.Year-2)','width':400,'height':300,legend:{position:'none'}};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_divb'));
            chart.draw(data,options);
        }
    </script>
</div>
<div id="chart_diva">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Interventions');
            var data1=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chartToday))
            $.each(data1,function(index,value){
                data.addRows([[value.Item1, value.Item2]]);
            });
            var options = {'title':'Total Interventions on @(DateTime.Now.Year-1)','width':400,'height':300,legend:{position:'none'}};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_diva'));
            chart.draw(data,options);
        }
    </script>
</div>


<div id="chart_div">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Interventions');
            var data1=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chartToday))
            $.each(data1,function(index,value){
                data.addRows([[value.Item1, value.Item2]]);
            });
            var options = {'title':'Total Interventions on @DateTime.Now.Year','width':400,'height':300,legend:{position:'none'}};
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data,options);
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

Every calls are working (I can see it in source code) but they are just not displayed.

Hope someone can help me and thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: first of all, you don't need to include the reference to the `charts/loaders.js` multiple times. just once.

Comment: second, you have two functions named `drawChart()`

Comment: @DLeh Ok I just keep one `charts/loaders.js` and I already tried to change the name of the functions `drawChart()` but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DLeh mentioned in the previous answer, you should follow the Google Charts guidelines on registering the chart library (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs). You only need to register the script and load the chart a single time.

As for displaying the 3 charts together horizontally there are various ways this could be done via CSS, but I just used float:left as a quick example.

---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="chart_div1" style="float: left;">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Interventions');
                    var data1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chartToday));
                    $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
                        data.addRows([[value.Item1, value.Item2]]);
                    });
                    var options = { 'title': 'Total Interventions on 1 @(DateTime.Now.Year - 2)', 'width': 400, 'height': 300, legend: { position: 'none' } };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <div id="chart_div2" style="float: left;">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Interventions');
                    var data1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chartToday));
                    $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
                        data.addRows([[value.Item1, value.Item2]]);
                    });
                    var options = { 'title': 'Total Interventions on 2 @(DateTime.Now.Year - 1)', 'width': 400, 'height': 300, legend: { position: 'none' } };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
        </div>


        <div id="chart_div3" style="float: left;">

            <script type="text/javascript">
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                    data.addColumn('string', 'Mois');
                    data.addColumn('number', 'Interventions');
                    var data1 = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chartToday));
                    $.each(data1, function(index, value) {
                        data.addRows([[value.Item1, value.Item2]]);
                    });
                    var options = { 'title': 'Total Interventions on 3 @DateTime.Now.Year', 'width': 400, 'height': 300, legend: { position: 'none' } };
                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why when I try to do this solution on my own it's not working and when I ask here it does ^^' Thank you @abrown !